# Difference between MVC 5 Layout Page (Razor) and Layout Page (Razor v3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following a tutorial ASP.NET MVC 5 from scratch, and right now I should add a _Layout.cshtml page in the Shared folder. Right clicking the Shared folder, I noticed in the context menu that you can add a 'MVC 5 Layout Page (Razor)'. But in the tutorial it says to

Add -> New Item -> Visual C# -> Web -> Razor -> Layout Page (Razor v3)

I selected them both, and wouldn't you know it, they are indeed somewhat different. But what is this difference? Is Layout Page (Razor v3) an older version? If not, what is the difference between the two, and which should I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor version 3 is the latest stable version.

If you are building an **MVC** site then use

- Add -> New Item -> Visual C# -> Web -> **MVC** -> MVC5 Layout Page (Razor)

The other option is for a [Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/aspnet-web-pages-razor-faq) site

- Add -> New Item -> Visual C# -> Web -> **Razor** -> Layout Page (Razor v3)

Comment: Since the tutorial creates an asp.net 5 mvc appliation from scratch, I wonder why the choice was for Layout Page (Razor v3). Though I read the link you provided, I'm still not clear as to what a web page actually is. It is not web forms, nor mvc, yet uses razor...?

Comment: Web Pages is a simple way to include some C# code in a Razor view without building an application with MVC or Web Forms. This [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started) might give you a better idea of what it is.